# Combining CSS background animations and transparent text fill color

Tags: css

I'm attempting to create an animated gradient background with transparent ("cut out") text over the top of an animated gradient background.

At the moment I have an animated gradient background - basically using the code from here: https://www.gradient-animator.com/

Then I have an absolutely positioned element over the top with a black background and a mixed-blend-mode attribute (currently darken).

This still doesn't look right as the mix-blend-mode affects the background too, where I just want the text to change.

I have a very rough idea here: https://codepen.io/twentyonehundred/pen/pNjpJW where the grey background clearly leaks some colour (a black background does not). There may be much better ways of achieving the effect I want?

Code:

```css
.element {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #2efdc7, #d71414, #146ed7);
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  animation: AnimationName 7s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 43%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 58%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 43%
  }
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #23282d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <h1>abcd</h1>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION EXAMPLE**

Below is an example of a working solution as suggested by Federico.

https://codepen.io/twentyonehundred/pen/pNjpJW

Comment: How about with SVG masks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sqhesuwp/1/). It could become very complex with CSS (if at all it is achievable that is).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, it's quite possibly the preferable way of doing this.

Comment: You're welcome buddy. Just a note of caution with respect to the `-webkit-background-clip: text`, it is a non-standard value which will not work in non WebKit browsers and there is no surity that it will not get removed. (*Edit:* I stand corrected. [It seems like FF supports this from v49](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) but it is still not recommended for production use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `-webkit-background-clip: text;`

```css
.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #23282d;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10vw;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #2efdc7, #d71414, #146ed7);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  animation: AnimationName 7s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 43%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 58%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 43%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <h1>abcd</h1>
</div>
```